# Select an item in a list on click with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to chenge the css class of a `li` tag when I click on it.

I have this:

#### Model:

```
var businessUnitsModel = {
    businessUnitsList: ko.observableArray([
        { siteID: "a", title: "business1" },
        { siteID: "b", title: "business2" }, 
        { siteID: "c", title: "business3" }, 
        { siteID: "d", title: "business4" }]),
    currentSelected: ko.observable(),
    selectItem: function (site) { this.currentSelected(site.siteID); }
}

//overall viewModel
var viewModel = {
    businessUnits: businessUnitsModel,
};
```

#### HTML

```
<ul class="modal-list" data-bind="'foreach': businessUnits.businessUnitsList">
    <li class="filterItem" data-bind="'text': title, 
        css: { 'filterItemSelect': siteID === $parent.currentSelected }, 
        'click': $parent.selectItem">
    </li> 
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.filterItemSelect {
    color:#0069ab;
}
```

and I can't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you are looking for :

JS:

```
var businessUnitsModel = {
    businessUnitsList: ko.observableArray([{
        siteID: "a",
        title: "business1"
    }, {
        siteID: "b",
        title: "business2"
    }, {
        siteID: "c",
        title: "business3"
    }, {
        siteID: "d",
        title: "business4"
    }]),
    currentSelected: ko.observable(),
    selectItem: function (that, site) {
        that.currentSelected(site.siteID);
    }
}

//overall viewModel
var viewModel = {
    businessUnits: businessUnitsModel,
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

View :

```
<div data-bind="with :businessUnits">
    <ul class="modal-list" data-bind="'foreach': businessUnitsList">
        <li class="filterItem" data-bind="'text': title, 
        css: { 'filterItemSelect': siteID === $parent.currentSelected() },
        'click': function(){$parent.selectItem($parent, $data);}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vUpZW/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, But why have you completely changed the structure of the OP's original view-model form `var viewModel = {
    businessUnits: businessUnitsModel,
};` to `new businessUnitsModel()`?

Comment: @Damien No you have not. :) As nemesv says I need the viewModel in the original way. That is the challenge. I know it works with a model like that.

Comment: Thanks Damien it's perfekt. I think the problem lied with the context in the viewModel. I think this line ´that.currentSelected(site.siteID);´ fixed it. :)

Comment: Actually you don't need a function selectItem here. Simply 'click': function(){$parent.currentSelected($data);}" will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use currentSelected function value (i.e. add parentheses) when applying css:

```
<ul class="modal-list" data-bind="foreach: businessUnitsList">
    <li class="filterItem" data-bind="text: title, 
        css: { 'filterItemSelect': siteID === $parent.currentSelected() }, 
        click: $parent.selectItem">
    </li> 
</ul>
```

And script:

```
var businessUnitsModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.businessUnitsList = ko.observableArray([
        { siteID: "a", title: "business1" },
        { siteID: "b", title: "business2" }, 
        { siteID: "c", title: "business3" }, 
        { siteID: "d", title: "business4" }]);
    self.currentSelected = ko.observable();
    self.selectItem = function (site) {        
        self.currentSelected(site.siteID);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new businessUnitsModel());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazyberezovsky/5dcs2/1/)

---

*UPDATE* here is update of your markup and view model. You should provide full path to `currentSelected()` property:

```
<ul class="modal-list" data-bind="'foreach': businessUnits.businessUnitsList">
    <li class="filterItem" data-bind="'text': title, 
        css: { 'filterItemSelect': 
               siteID === $parent.businessUnits.currentSelected() }, 
        'click': $parent.businessUnits.selectItem">
    </li> 
</ul>
```

And here is fixed problem with model - inside `selectItem` function `this` was equal to item which you clicked. Thus you don't want to use `self` alias to model, you need to specify its name:

```
var businessUnitsModel = {
    businessUnitsList: ko.observableArray([
        { siteID: "a", title: "business1" },
        { siteID: "b", title: "business2" }, 
        { siteID: "c", title: "business3" }, 
        { siteID: "d", title: "business4" }]),
    currentSelected: ko.observable(),
    selectItem: function (site) {         
        businessUnitsModel.currentSelected(site.siteID); 
    }
}

//overall viewModel
var viewModel = {
    businessUnits: businessUnitsModel,
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazyberezovsky/5dcs2/3/)

Comment: Ok, But why have you completely changed the structure of the OP's original view-model form `var viewModel = {
    businessUnits: businessUnitsModel,
};` to `new businessUnitsModel()`?

Comment: @nemesv well, it was more easy to me) And OP didn't provide all script from the beginning. I'll update answer in a moment

Comment: Exactly, as nemesv says I need the viewModel in the original way. That is the challenge. I know it works with a model like that. Can you try the other way?